# Peer to peer payments using PayPal gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I plan on using the [PayPal gem](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK) in my Rails application, but after reading the docs and watching the Railscast on it, I am still uncertain if the gem allows users to send money to one another.

Is there a particular part of the PayPal docs I should have a look at? I read into the PayPal Adaptive payments but that still seems like it is for the merchant to pay several people rather than for users to pay each other.

Comment: If you mean the [official PayPal gem](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK) it's meant for other people to pay _you_. I think all you can really do in this case is to send users to PayPal's website.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar to Stripe Connect but under paypal if it is available

Answer (score 0):

You were looking at the REST API gem which has not yet included the P2P/platform feature (in the up-to-date release).

Adaptive Payments would work in your case to allow P2P payments on your platform, where you're supposed to be the API caller, and transactions are made from sender to reciever(you identified in the 'PAY' API call) on your platform.

See more scenario descriptions [HERE](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/)

And you should look for the classic SDKs which Adaptive Payments are included
SDK - [Github repo for Adaptive Payments gem](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-ruby)